# What is Malebranche's explanation for the source of human error?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, metaphysics, descartes, aquinas

An omnibenevolent God would not deceive us or cause us to be in error, thus the gifts from  cannot be the source of error. Rather sin confuses our faculties and prevents us from using them as they were meant to be and causes error.... I don't think I understand this at all. Can anybody help me figure out how Malebranche explains how humans can err?

Comment: See [Malebranche's Theodicy](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/malebranche/#The): "God produces the natural evils that follow from simple laws not because He wills those particular effects, but because He wills a world that best reflects His wisdom by possessing the most effects governed by the fewest laws."